# Opening a connection to a webserver (controller) and keeping it alive

Tags: php

is it possible to open a connection to a "server" in php and let that server send commands later to that page without the need of the user to reload it?

**Better Explanation**: When a user joins our index.php, a connection will be open to a "server" on the same domain, that server will later send some data to all "users" connected to it, and the php would parse it and display the data.

Is it possible? If yes, what should I look for?

Comment: I think you should use nodejs specially meterojs

Comment: websockets, longpolling etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesome, guys, seems like websockets are exactly what I need!
Thanks for the Ideas!

Comment: ohh, bad choice to use websockets for webapp, you should use longpoll for webapp